# Java Virtual Machine couldn.t be loaded error in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I downloaded Eclipse RCP (I am using 64 bit Windows 10). I could download only 32 bit exe file from the eclipse website. After downloading I am getting the error "Couldn't create Java Virtual Machine". How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a 32bit or a 64bit Java? Why couldn't you download the 64bit Eclipse version?

Comment: You have to use a 32 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit Java or a 64 bit Eclipse with a 64 bit Java.  Eclipse and Java have to have the same bit size.